# ローカル環境で接続できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Ruby on Rails 5 速習実践ガイドで勉強している初心者です。
５章の「テストをはじめよう」の、rspecによるテスト（205ﾍﾟｰｼﾞ）で、テストを実行しても失敗してしまい、先に進まない状態で悩まされています。
一連のコード自体は何度も見返し問題ないのですが。
ローカルでの接続が拒否されているようですが。
ubuntu wsl ruby2.5.1 rails5.2.1?5.2.2かも です。
chromedriverがないのか？chromedriver-helperはインストールされているし。

＜エラー内容＞

```
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:55084
F

Failures:

  1) タスク管理機能 一覧表示機能 ユーザーＡがログインしているとき ユーザーＡが作成したタスクが表示される
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: visit login_path

          Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
            Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)



          # ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
          #   Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515
          #   ./spec/system/tasks_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error:
            raise e, "Failed to open TCP connection to " +
              "#{conn_address}:#{conn_port} (#{e.message})"

          Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
            Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)
>
> [直訳]　同じマシン(ipアドレス：127.0.0.1)の9515番ポートにconnectionを開こうとしましたが、失敗しました

というメッセージが出ているのですから、9515ポートでListenしているべきプロセスが起動されていないか、起動に失敗しているかだと思われます。

一度マシンを再起動して、Ruby on Railsの起動からやり直してみてください。
そして、その際にプロセスの起動に失敗した旨のメッセージが出ないか確認してください。

9515番ポートはChrome Driverが使うポートなので、chromedriverが起動されているか確認してください。